# TypeError: Cannot read property "name" of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am dealing with inputs and pushing their name into state to render on the page. Right now the user can only choose one image so I came up with if statements to allow the user to select more than one image but I am getting an error that reads `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])

const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.target.files[0].name && event.target.files[1].name && event.target.files[2].name) {

        const name = event.target.files[0].name
        const nameTwo = event.target.files[1].name
        const nameThree = event.target.files[2].name

        setFiles(files => [...files, name])
        setFiles(files => [...files, nameTwo])
        setFiles(files => [...files, nameThree])

    } else if (event.target.files[0].name && event.target.files[1].name) {

        const name = event.target.files[0].name
        const nameTwo = event.target.files[1].name

        setFiles(files => [...files, name])
        setFiles(files => [...files, nameTwo])

    } else if (event.target.files[0].name) {

        const name = event.target.files[0].name
        setFiles(files => [...files, name])

    }

    files.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of error mean that your container variable files[0] not defined. You should check event.target.files[x] is exist then use name property. Change your code to

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])

const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.target.files[0] && event.target.files[1] && event.target.files[2]) {

        const name = event.target.files[0].name
        const nameTwo = event.target.files[1].name
        const nameThree = event.target.files[2].name

        setFiles(files => [...files, name])
        setFiles(files => [...files, nameTwo])
        setFiles(files => [...files, nameThree])

    } else if (event.target.files[0] && event.target.files[1] ) {

        const name = event.target.files[0].name
        const nameTwo = event.target.files[1].name

        setFiles(files => [...files, name])
        setFiles(files => [...files, nameTwo])

    } else if (event.target.files[0]) {

        const name = event.target.files[0].name
        setFiles(files => [...files, name])

    }

    files.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: @Grimygod This solution works, but it's still using a relatively convoluted approach to this problem. See my answer for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing this issue because you're assuming that all of those elements (at indices 0 through 2) exist in the `files` array in the first place. You're also taking a convoluted approach to doing this. You can replace your entire `handleChange` logic with one line.

```js
setFiles(files => [
    ...files, ...Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.files).map(f => f.name)
]);
```